# What's a good solution to have a configuration settings specific to a machine?

Tags: c#

HI,
I want to have set configuration settings for a unit test project that is only relative for one machine ( i.e build machine). So for e.g. is the unit test project is being compiled on a developer machine then use settings A from App.config, if it's compiled on a build machine then use settings B from App.config. Is there a best practice for this sort of things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the appSettings tag, you can add an attribute like:

```
<appSettings file="moreSettings.config">
```

Inside the 'moreSettings.config' file, you create an  tag that contains key-value pairs for any of the key-value pairs that you want to override from the main App.config file.

Comment: +1 - I use this frequently; especially for the `connectionStrings` element.

Answer (score 0):

you can use conditional compilation symbols (just same as macro in C/C++) also...

Answer (score 0):

Well, i guess you could check the hostname (this should be possible in almost any language or build environment) and depending on that decide what settings to use.

However i would not advise you to "automagicly" decide to do a developer/debug build. But rather i would suggest you provide a "switch" either on comandline or in a config file. Which you than explicitly enable in your setup on the development/test machine.